# Why does writing a list of words to a CSV file write the individual characters instead?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a list to a csv file in Python. This list has strings for elements (list sample: `['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit']`). I use this code to write that list to a csv:

```
with open("PATH HERE", "w", newline='') as wfl:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(wfl, delimiter=",")
    for word in words:
        csvwriter.writerow(word)
```

But the results are not what I want...

```
L,o,r,e,m
i,p,s,u,m
d,o,l,o,r
s,i,t
```

I want it to be a word per value and not a character per value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't want to write each word as a row, so don't use "for word in words". Just use csvwriter.writerow(words)

Comment: Your list is the row. You are treating each word as a separate row.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yeap found it right after, thanks!